# jquery Replace DIV data and then track clicks on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have a `<div id="myContainer"></div>` .
I also have a button: `<input type="button" value="Send" id="sendButton">`
While clicking at the button: it replaces the DIV with another:

```
$( "#sendButton" ).click(function() {
$( "#myContainer" ).replaceWith("<div id='calc'><input type=\"text\" id=\"screen\" value=0><button id=\"add\">+</button><button id=\"mul\">*</button><button id=\"settings\">settings</button><button id=\"clear\">clear</button></div>");
});
```

I want to activate another function after click on a new button I've just put (`<button id=\"mul\">*</button>`):

```
$( "#mul" ).click(function() {
console.log(' mul clicked!');
});
```

Which doesn't work, the fact that I'm waiting for a click on a div that just created have something to do with it?

Comment: Your screen name on SO is kinda awesome! @fgf...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call `$( "#mul" ).click()`, you're attaching an event handler to `#mul` as it exists at that point. To fix this, just call `$( "#mul" ).click()` *after* you create `#mul`.

```
$( "#sendButton" ).click(function() {
    $( "#myContainer" ).replaceWith("<div id='calc'><input type=\"text\" id=\"screen\" value=0><button id=\"add\">+</button><button id=\"mul\">*</button><button id=\"settings\">settings</button><button id=\"clear\">clear</button></div>");
    $( "#mul" ).click(function() {
        console.log( ' mul clicked!' );
    });
});
```

You could also use jQuery's `.on` method with the optional selector, called a *delegated event handler* according to the documentation. Take a look at the API for jQuery if that's what you want: [jQuery API documentation](http://api.jquery.com/on/). The basic usage would be something like

```
$( document ).on( "click", "#mul", function( ) {
    console.log( ' mul clicked!' );
});
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to attach event to `#mul`. Because it is appended dynamically, `$("#mul").click()` will not work.

`.on()` attaches event handlers to the currently selected set of elements.

Try:

```
$("body").on("click","#mul",function(){
    console.log("mul clicked!");
});
```

[More information here.](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
$(document).on("click","#mul",function() {
```

instead of

```
$( "#mul" ).click(function() {
```

**or**

```
    $( "#sendButton" ).click(function() {
        $( "#myContainer" ).replaceWith("<div id='calc'><input type=\"text\" id=\"screen\" value=0><button id=\"add\">+</button><button id=\"mul\">*</button><button id=\"settings\">settings</button><button id=\"clear\">clear</button></div>");
        $( "#mul" ).click(function() {
           console.log(' mul clicked!');
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#sendButton" ).click(function() {
$( "#myContainer" ).replaceWith("<div id='calc'><input type=\"text\" id=\"screen\" value=0><button id=\"add\">+</button><button id=\"mul\">*</button><button id=\"settings\">settings</button><button id=\"clear\">clear</button></div>");

// add listener here
$( "#mul" ).click(function() {
console.log(' mul clicked!');
});

$( "#mul" ).trigger("click"); // add this to your code

});
```

http://api.jquery.com/trigger/ see detail of trigger()

http://jsfiddle.net/tnnj5/ here is a demo

you must add listener after the new content has insert into dom

Comment: This is not what the OP is asking how to do. This will do the equivalent of clicking the button, he is wanting to know why his click event handler is not working on an element that he has dynamically created after document load. You can do this by replacing the .click call with the answer by @Hiral

Comment: @TomHeard yes. i did not read the question carfully.. but it seems that i have solved the problem by accident :)

Comment: I did notice that as I was commenting, which is why I tried not to say that your answer was wrong, it just had the wrong intent. =P

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) method to bind event with dynamically added content.

Try this:

```
 $("#mul").live("click", function() {
    console.log(' mul clicked!');
 });
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6YUZ/)

You can also use jquery `.on()`, But here you add dynamic content. So you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler like:

```
$(document).on("click","body #mul", function() {
    console.log(' mul clicked!');
 });
```

[Try in jsfiddle with on](http://jsfiddle.net/Y6YUZ/3/)